# How can I tell if an elisp expression is pure and constant?

Tags: expression, elisp, constant-expression

At some point, Emacs added the `pure` symbol property, indicating which functions are known to be pure (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Properties.html)). Is there a way to use this property to determine if an entire expression is constant and side-effect-free? For example, it's pretty easy to determine that `(car '(1 2 3))` is a constant expression, since `car` is a pure function (i.e. `(get 'car 'pure)` returns t) and `'(1 2 3)` is a quoted form. However, there are more complex expressions, e.g. involving special forms, which are still constant:

```lisp
(let ((a (+ 1 2))
      (b (- 5 5)))
  (if (> b 0)
      a
    (- a)))
```

Notably, neither `let` nor `if` is marked as pure, but this is still a constant expression evaluating to -3.

Is there any way I can take an arbitrary expression and determine whether it is constant? I know there is `unsafep`, which appears to implement the necessary expression tree walking, but it is evaluating a different criterion than "constant", so I can't use it directly.

- It's fine to assume that none of the definitions of standard Elisp functions, macros, or special forms (`car`, `let`, `if`, etc.) have been modified.
- For my purposes, "constant" is defined using `equal`. So a function that returns a new list on each call with the same contents every time would be considered constant.
- I know there are some constant expressions that involve impure functions, e.g. `(nreverse '(1 2 3))`. I don't mind if the algorithm misses such expressions.

In case it matters, the reason I want to do this is that I'm implementing an elisp macro where constant expressions occurring in a certain context are syntactically valid, but their return value will be ignored, making them pointless, and likely the result of a programmer misunderstanding. So I want to issue a warning if the macro sees a constant expression in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can take an arbitrary expression and determine whether it is constant?

No.

---

First, whenever lisp interpreter sees a symbol it's interned in `obarray` (object array) if it's never seen before. So in a very strict sense, most functions cannot be side-effect free.

Also, by definition some operations has side effects. For example, IO has side effects as it reads from `stdin` or writes to `stdout`/`stderr`.

So we need to limit the definition of `side-effect-free` to not changing external states. For example, the following must not be `side-effect-free`:

```lisp
;; If a function modifies one of its input argument
(defvar foo nil)
(funcall (lambda () (setq foo t)))

;; If a function modifies a free variable. Here `free variable` means any non-constant ;; symbol from the enclosing environment
(funcall (lambda (x) (setq x t)) foo)
(funcall (lambda (x) (makunbound x)) 'foo)

;; If a function initialize a variable in the enclosing environment
(funcall (lambda (x) (defvar bar nil)))
```

---

Second, `pure` function must be `side-effect-free` AND returns the same output given same input.

`constant` in this context doesn't mean a symbol has an invariable value. It means the value of `sexp` can be known at compile time. This is related to, but not equal, `referential transparency`. If a `sexp` is `constant`, the byte compiler can simply replace the `sexp` by its value.

That is, `(declare (pure t))` tells the compiler that, if all input arguments of this function are constant (they're known at compile time), the output can be computed at compile time.

---

To determine whether a function is `side-effect-free`, you just need to check the symbol property `side-effect-free` or `pure` of the symbol. Or you can use:

```lisp
(defun side-effect-free-p (function)
  (and (symbolp function)
       (or (function-get function 'pure)
           (funciton-get function 'side-effect-free))))
```

Similarly,

```lisp
(defun pure-p (function)
  (and (symbolp fucntion)
       (function-get function 'pure)))
```

---

The vast majority of functions are neither `side-effect-free` nor `pure`, but they can be `side-effect-free` or `pure` in specific invocation. For example,

```lisp
;; `let` - pure and side-effect free
(let ((foo nil))
  nil)

;; `let` - neither pure nor side-effect free
(defvar bar t)
(let ((foo (setq bar nil))) ; modified outside state, bar
  nil)

;; `let` - not pure but side-effect free
(let ((foo (current-time))) ; the first argument to let, not constant
  foo)
(let ()           ; empty local binding specification
  (current-time)) ; the second argument to let, it's not constant
```